# Windows 8 manipulate tiles

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Can I manipulate the tiles from C++ application (through WinAPI/WinRT, register or something else)?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unspecific. Look at these samples [1](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148) and [2](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Secondary-Tiles-Sample-edf2a178) to get started with Tiles and C++. If you've got a more specific/detailed question feel free to ask.

Edit: (method names and namespaces are from c# but should be ~equal in c++)

- Primary tiles can only be deleted by the user.
- You can access limited WinRT functionality out of an non MetroApp. But as far as I know there is no way to delete foreign tiles in the "limited" WinRT.
- If you want to delete secondary tiles you have to use `Windows.UI.StartScreen.SecondaryTile.FindAllAsync("id of the app tiles belong to");` and then call `tile.RequestDeleteAsync()` for each tile in the result you want to remove. Note that every delete request must be accepted by user. As already mentioned `Windows.UI.StartScreen` namespace is only available out of metro apps.

Comment: the problem is that I have non-metro MFC/С++ application and should be delete titles. Maybe can be accessed to WinRT through COM etc...